# Index delta connection refused React Native

Tags: javascript, react-native

Situation - I'm running on custom vagrant vm ip address .i.e. 10.10.10.10

The app compiles fine, however, when I  try to switch on the debugger, it fetches from `localhost:8081` which is not available.

However, when I try to change it to `10.10.10.10:8081/index.delta...` it is able to fetch the required information.

Where is this debugging configuration defined, so that this works fine? :)
[image]